# Python semi-noob, can someone explain why this phonomena occurs in 'Lists'

Tags: python

I'm working on a small app that pulls data out of a list stored in a list, passes it through a class init, and then displays/allows user to work. Everything was going fine until i tried to format the original 'list' in the IDLE so it was easier to read (for me). so I'd change 9 to 09,  8 to 08. etc It was a simple formating/spacing change and it broke the entire god damn program, citing 'invalid token'.  WTF is this, I thought.  So then I opened the interpreter and started typing:

```
>x = [5,5]  #Control

>x

[5, 5]

>>> y=[05,05]    #control2

>>> y

[5, 5]

>>> z = [05, "ge"]  #test. 'Integer', before string, apparantly works.


>>> z

[5, 'ge']

> a = ["ge", 09]  #test2. String, before 'integer', cocks things up.

SyntaxError: invalid token

>>> b= ["ge", 9]    #test3, this works fine.


>>> b


['ge', 9]
```

I guess my question is... why does this occur? Why is python interpret these integers as 'tokens' when they follow strings, but as integers when they follow integers?

Answer (score 7):

It's nothing to do with lists or strings. When you prefix a number with `0`, it's interpreted as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). And 9 is not a valid octal digit!

```
Python 2.7.6 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 09
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    09
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 011
9
```

Note that in Python3, this gives you the error for any 0-prefixed number, presumably to reduce confusion of the type you are experiencing. To specify octal in Python3, you must use `0o` as a prefix.

```
Python 3.3.3 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 09
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    09
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 011
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    011
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 0o11
9
>>> 0o9
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    0o9
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>>
```

Comment: Many thanks all who answered. Upvotes for all!  I had actually noticed that some 0+ numbers seemed to work, but was unsure why. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

It's not just Python, it's most programming languages. Starting a number with a zero signifies that the number is in octal, which means only digits `0-7` are valid. Thus,

```
5 == 05
6 == 06
7 == 07
8 == 010
9 == 011
...
15 == 017
16 == 020
...
255 == 0377
```

Similarly, prefix `0x` means the number is hexadecimal (so, valid digits are `0-9` and `a-f`: `255 == 0xff`)

Answer (score 3):

This is because python interprets numbers with a `0` in front of them as octal, so saying `09` doesn't make much sense.

If you changed it for instance to the following:

```
a = ["ge", 07]
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is because if the digit starts with a `0` it is considered an octal digit and octal digits are only from`0-7`

#### Example

```
>>> 015 - 02   #which is obviously not what you'd expect for base10 integers
11
```